# Change loading bar colour in NSIS Installer

Tags: winapi, installation, nsis

**How I change the colour of the Loading Bar in the Install Files page of an NSIS installer?**

The following attempts to send the message PBM_SETBARCOLOR to the loading bar window but the colour of the load bar never changes?

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh

InstallDir  "abc"
Name        "def"        
OutFile     "def.exe"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW InstFilesPageShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!macro RefreshWindow HWND IDC
    GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
    ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
    ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_SHOW}
!macroend

Function InstFilesPageShow

    SendMessage 1004 ${PBM_SETBARCOLOR} 0 "COLORREF(0,200,200)" #0xFF0000
    System::Call `user32::SendMessage(i R1, i ${PBM_SETBARCOLOR}, i 0, i COLORREF(0,0,0))`  #System::Call `user32::SetWindowPos(i R8, i ${HWND_TOP}, i 0, i 0, i ${w}, i ${h}, i ${SWP_NOMOVE})`
    #!insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWND 1004
    #!insertmacro RefreshWindow $mui.InstallPage 1004
    !insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1004

FunctionEnd

Section "Dummy" 
    DetailPrint "Test"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: COLORREF is a Win32 type, not a macro/function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XPStyle on
Page instfiles "" instfilesShow

!include WinMessages.nsh

Function instfilesShow
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1004
System::Call UxTheme::SetWindowTheme(ir0,w"",w"")
SendMessage $0 ${PBM_SETBARCOLOR} 0 0x11aaee
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you won't be able to do this : in the [PBM_SETBARCOLOR documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), MSDN states

> When visual styles are enabled, this message has no effect.

BTW, in your `RefreshWindow` macro, you are incorrectly getting the control handle from its ID. NSIS documentation tells

> If you want to get the handle of a control on the inner dialog, first use `FindWindow user_var(output) "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT` to get the handle of the inner dialog.

Thus you can write like this :

```
FindWindow $R1 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT ;$R1 = handle of the inner dialog
GetDlgItem $R0 $R1 ${IDC} ;get the handle of control from its ID
ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_SHOW}
```